# Refine and @ (at) symbol in Coq 8.5pl1

Tags: coq

In the previous version of Coq using symbol @ in refine command allows me to create a prove step-by-step. (Each argument was a separate goal.)

I want to avoid implicit arguments like "?Goal0 ?Goal1". And now I can not.
What should I do obtain such possibility?

(It is very uncomfortable to me especially when I trying to deal with recursive functions.)

Comment: **(1)** Could you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? **(2)** Coq 8.5pl1 manual, §2.11: "Existential variables are generated in place of unsolvable implicit arguments or “_” placeholders ... when using tactics such as `refine`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `simple refine`.

In 8.5, goals that can be solved by unification (what you call implicit) are put in the "shelve" a hidden area, as they are considered trivial. You can unshelve them with `Unshelve` but it is a bit incovenient as it is a vernacular command.

`simple refine` behaves as 8.4 and doesn't put anything in the shelve.